# What are the duties to be followed after initiation under a Vaishnava Guru?

Tags: customs, guru

Being part of a Vaishnava family, I had undergone a ceremony for having Guru when I was 10 years old. The only duty I followed after that is to wear "kanthi" so I wanted to know what are the other duties or customs that I should follow?

Comment: depends.. what vaishnava sect is your family - gaudiya/iskcon? btw, why don't you ask the Guru himself ?